# Remove toolbar entry from taskbar's Toolbar menu

Tags: windows-8, taskbar, toolbar

I tried several times through to uninstall the program which has this toolbar but the program seems to have a problem with Windows 8 so I removed it using REVO Uninstaller. Nevertheless, the entry there wasn't removed during the forced uninstallation process. **Is there a a way to remove entries from the list of toolbars in the taskbar's toolbar menu?**

[image: See here to understand what I mean]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran Piriform's CCleaner program, using it's Cleaner and Registry Cleaner module, and it deleted the entry.

Comment: What exactly in CCleaner did you run? The registry scan? The cleanup? The uninstall? The startup programs list?

Comment: I ran cleaner and the registry cleaner,but I think that the cleaner did the job